# Deploy an asp.net package, sql databases and modify (text-)files

Tags: powershell, wix, installation

we are currently using a powershell script (~800 lines of code) to deploy an asp.net website, setting up the databases and modifying some xml nodes / text files. Can we use the wix toolset to do that? I am not very familiar with it. Or is it possible to copy our installation folder to the target system and executing the powershell file on it, using the wix toolset?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WIX can handle this.

You can start with this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115036/Creating-WIX-Installer-for-ASP-NET-Web-Application) that includes enabling feature in IIS, installing website and change config files.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar question / problem. My problem was that I couldn't get a powershell script working. I wrote a guide [over here](https://blog.jdstaerk.de/wix-toolset-powershell-custom-action/) that migth help you. Feel free to ask if you need further assistance! :)